# Method for optimizing a function based on empirical data for two variables

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

I'm trying to work out a formula to optimize a certain real-world outcome, which is mostly a function of two other variables. I can gather as many empirical data points as I like to refine the formula. For example, let's say I have the following data points:

| Given *a* | Variable *b* | Result *c* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 4 | 10 |
| 1200 | 5 | 10.4 |
| 2200 | 10 | 9.9 |
| 1000 | 4 | 10.1 |

Note that rows 1 and 4 have the same inputs, but different outputs, because this is real-world empirical data, and sometimes there's a little bit of jitter in the results.

My objective is to come up with a formula such that for any given value of *a*, I can choose a value for *b* that will give me the highest possible value for *c*, and continually improve my formula as I gather more empirical data.

How should I go about this?

---

**Motivation**

I am trying to download files of different sizes ($a$ is the size) from the same server, and I want to work out how many chunks ($b$ is the number of chunks) to break the file into to optimize the average download speed ($c$ is the average speed). Hence, $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, and $c$ is real.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are horrible names for inputs. $c$ is a horrible name for an output.  Are the inputs reals or integers? You mentioned nothing about your function. What do you know about it? What real-world motivation are we talking about?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Ok, I'll give you the real-world case; I just didn't want to confuse things by being too specific. I'm trying to download files of different sizes (a=size) from the same server, and I want to work out how many chunks (b=no of chunks) to break the file into to optimize the average download speed (c=average speed). So, a and b are positive integers, c is real.

Comment: Have you tried coming up with a model for your function?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I don't have much real-world experience with this kind of problem. I'm a software engineer, not a mathematician :-) - but I hope I'm good enough at math to understand any proposed answers.

Comment: As for a basic model, I would expect average speed to increase with more parallelization, with the limitation that each chunk comes with an overhead that will limit the effectiveness of breaking the file into too many chunks.

Comment: Don't sell yourself short.  Physicists are known for modeling, not mathematicians.

Comment: Is the rate (bits per second) constant?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo we can't assume a constant transfer rate. The number of parallel threads could very well slow down the rate per thread. The only way we'll know how much is by taking empirical measurements. Also, there's the ambient Internet jitter that's completely out of our control.

Comment: I meant the rate of the connection.

Comment: Is this equivalent to an army attempting to cross a river and deciding how many barges to use?  The overhead would be the number of sailors per barge. All barges travel at the same constant speed once on water.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes, we can assume that our Internet connection speed is constant. At least, that won't be a limiting factor. I'm not sure how you would view this as a problem of an army crossing a river? The analogy doesn't seem valid, since data is by default sent in series, and you specifically have to chunk it to achieve parallelization, whereas a barge by definition is taking soldiers across in parallel, so if you could fit all your soldiers in one infinite-capacity barge, your problem is solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139932/discussion-between-shaul-behr-and-rodrigo-de-azevedo).